# Question about equalizing collectionView Cell size that varies from device to device in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

[image]

As the size of the collectionView cell grows, the cell alignment between the small screen device models (iphone 5s / se / 6/7/8) and the large screen device models (iphone 8+ / XR / XS max) changes.

Like the picture below, I want to use the above picture with cell with almost no margin of collectionView.

How can I resize the collectionView cell from device to device?

Comment: Just ask for the Screensize and set your values depending on the result. UIScreen.main.size (I am not sure whether the name is size, check the doc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
           sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

here if you are setting the size of the collectionviewcell make the width of cell

```
return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/ 2, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2)
```

Please set width and height property according to your need i have only divide it by 2 for simplicity .